# Resizing root window of a frame to 80 characters

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to find a command that would resize the current frame "only one window is open" to be 80 characters wide.

I am not trying to enlarge or minimize a buffer but instead just readjust the current buffer open to fit 80 character lines.

Comment: Check out the function `set-frame-size` and related functions -- e.g., `set-frame-width`; `set-frame-height`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-and-Position.html

Comment: Awesome! Thanks lawlist, you always come to the rescue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following link to the Emacs documentation relating to frames contains explanations of functions dealing with sizing frames:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-and-Position.html

Height and width can be set in one fell swoop using `set-frame-size`, which can even be set pixelwise using the additional argument.  Or, the height and width can be set separately with functions such as `set-frame-height` and `set-frame-width`.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameSize says you can also use

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(height . 24))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(width . 80))
```

in your `.emacs` / `.emacs.d/init.el` file.